# Keep on changing the address of database in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Everytime I run my app, database address is changed so my update or retrieval is not successfully working.

Any one can help me why this is happening with me... here my code to copy my database to the directory.

```
    (BOOL)createDB
    {
         NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
         NSError *error;

         NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
         dataPath=dbPath;
         databasePath = dbPath;
         NSLog(@"Path is:   %@",dbPath);
         BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

         if(!success) {

            NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]              resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"babynames.sqlite"];

           success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

              if (!success)
                  NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
          }
           return  success;

          }
```

Here is getDBPathCode

```
- (NSString *)getDBPath
{`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`
    //Search for standard documents using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    //First Param = Searching the documents directory
    //Second Param = Searching the Users directory and not the System
    //Expand any tildes and identify home directories.

    'NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"dbpath : %@",documentsDir);
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"babynames.sqlite"];'
}
```

Comment: So the filemanager doesn't find the copied version of the db?

Comment: I haven't find any issue in this code. just looks fine

Comment: What are the single quotes in your second method for? I have never seen that before.